# Trying to Fetch Graph/Charts from pdf using pdf operators. Is it Feasible to do so

Tags: pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to filter pdf pages which contain chart/graph information and separating it. I am trying to check whether operator pattern follows the sequence [q, cm, m, l], then there may be chart/graph there.

It is filtering pages but, fetching pages with just have tables, few graphics icons alose.

Not Sure, is it possible to fetch it the way im doing

Comment: You can see the operators of a page content stream by using the `PDFStreamParser` class. To see how this class can be used, have a look at the `RemoveAllText.java` example in the source code download. Your question is really unclear, because you have not showed what you tried.

Comment: I am first removing all text then analyzing existing operators with a pattern which I find common with many graphs [q, cm, m, l]

Comment: Please find attached the link for code I have done:  https://github.com/Deepak-Dhaka/PdGraphCheck/blob/master/PdfCheckGraph.java

Comment: You haven't shared the PDF file. From your code I see that you did parse + analyse the content stream  (although only the top level - your "graph" could be in a form Xobject!) But I think I understand now what your question is: you asking what strategy is best to recognize whether it is a graph or a table. I can't answer that because there is no "rule" on how a graph must look. What you could also do is to look at your files with PDFDebugger.

Comment: @TilmanHausherr  I am using pdfxplorer for debugging pdf internals, do you have any better option.

Comment: PDFDebugger, but I looked at the screenshots of pdfxplorer, it looks very pretty and is a similar concept. One difference is that PDFDebugger color-codes the PDF operators but that isn't so important. If all your files are created by the same software and version, then you might recognize some patterns, but if they are different files, then it will be difficult.